# MySQL query with list of values

Tags: mysql, django

I have a table with over then 50kk rows.

trackpoint:

```
+----+------------+-------------------+
| id | created_at | tag               |
+----+------------+-------------------+
|  1 | 1484407910 | visitorDevice643  |
|  2 | 1484407913 | visitorDevice643  |
|  3 | 1484407916 | visitorDevice643  |
|  4 | 1484393575 | anonymousDevice16 |
|  5 | 1484393578 | anonymousDevice16 |
+----+------------+-------------------+
```

where 'created_at' is a timestamp of row added.
and i have a list of timestamps, for example like this one:

```
timestamps = [1502744400, 1502830800, 1502917200]
```

I need to select all timestamp in every interval between i and i+1 of timestamp.

Using Django ORM it's look like:

```
step = 86400
for ts in timestamps[:-1]:    
    trackpoint_set.filter(created_at__gte=ts,created_at__lt=ts + step).values('tag').distinct().count()
```

Because of actually timestamps list is very very longer and table has many of rows, finally i getting 500 time-out

So, my question is, how to for it in ONE raw SQL query join rows and list of values, so it looks like `[(1502744400, 650), (1502830800, 1550)...]`

Where second first value is timestamp, and the second is count of unique tags in each interval.

Comment: What's 650? What's 1550? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my question

Comment: have you got an index on created_at? if it is a large query the index might give you a massive performance boost.

Comment: Yes, i do, and i tried UNIQUE pair tag-created_at, this didn't help too

Comment: But in your sample data set there is only one tag in each interval.

Comment: Anyway, you have a minimum timestamp and maximum timestamp (1502744400 and 1502917200) in your example, so you can limit your query to that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First index `created_at`. Next build query like `created_at in (timestamp, timestamp+1)`. For each timestamp, run the query one by one rather than all at once.

Comment: As I said, because the table is very large and the array is much longer, I get 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: Please try one batch at a time.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't help, If my step id 10min(600sec) in period of one day(86400sec) i actually get 144 iterations. And finally i get 504